# jquery: using delegates on same class but in different div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datepicker

I am using delegates to set a date-picker for text-box on focus event

I have got two different div with textbox having class='mydatepicker'

using the jQuery date-picker.

```
$('#div1').on('focus', '.mydatepicker', function(){   $(this).datepicker();});

$('#div2').on('focus', '.mydatepicker', function(){   $(this).datepicker();});
```

My code works fine but wanted to know if i can combine the two function.(re factoring)

I tried using multiple selectors but its not working in case of delegates

Thanks

Comment: Can you show the html part as well?

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can use [multiple selectors](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)

```
$('#div1, #div2').on('focus', '.mydatepicker', function(){   $(this).datepicker();});
```

Comment: @user3273621 jquery and jquery ui versions used

Comment: oh thanks- my bad sir i was not using , between selector. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can combine them using [**Multiple Selector ("selector1, selector2, selectorN")**](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)

```
$('#div1, #div2').on('focus', '.mydatepicker', function () {
    $(this).datepicker();
});
```